# OOzie: Unable to find hive-default.xml

Tags: hive, cloudera, oozie

I am new to oozie and want to add a hive job to my workflow. Could you please tell me where could I find or how could I create the hive-default.xml. I have actually installed everthing via cloudera manager and I am not sure where to find this file. I have looked for it in /etc/hive/conf which seems to be its usual directory but it is not there in that folder. I also did a find command in the terminal and it didn't pull up any file. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In /etc/hive/conf you should have hive-site.xml. You can copy this file to your HDFS workflow directory and rename it to hive-default.xml, should work.